# Storing values from safe-money

Tags: haskell

I've been playing around with `safe-money` and I got this basic setup:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

module Example where

import           Money
import           GHC.TypeLits

data Side = Buy | Sell

data Trade src dst fee = T
    { trade_exchange :: ExchangeRate src dst
    , trade_side     :: Side
    , trade_amount   :: Dense src
    , trade_fee      :: Dense fee
    }

executeTrade
    :: (Dense src, Dense dst, Dense fee)
    -> Trade src dst fee
    -> (Dense src, Dense dst, Dense fee)
executeTrade (balanceSrc, balanceDst, balanceFee) T {..} = case trade_side of
    Sell -> (balanceSrc - amountSrc, balanceDst + amountDst, totalFee)
    Buy  -> (balanceSrc + amountSrc, balanceDst - amountDst, totalFee)
  where
    amountSrc = trade_amount
    amountDst = exchange trade_exchange trade_amount
    totalFee  = balanceFee - trade_fee
```

And now I want to add a balance sheet... but I've been scratching my head for a long time trying to figure out how. Conceptually, I want to be able to map an asset with the name to a `Dense name` (or to the better `Discrete' name scale`). Since I wanted to have flexibility on how to actually get the balance sheet, I thought about having a type-class:

```hs
newtype Asset (name :: Symbol) = A Symbol

class BalanceSheet a where
   balance :: GoodScale scale => a -> Asset name -> Discrete' name scale
```

and I'm stuck. I feel like I'm missing a bit of theory, and I'm not sure how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. The part I was missing was that I didn't think about moving the name of the currency from the type level to a value I can work with on the term level: this is possible with `Proxy`, and in fact, `SomeDiscrete` uses that.

Here's the code

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module Example where

import qualified Data.Map                      as M
import           Data.Maybe
import           Data.Proxy
import           GHC.TypeLits
import           Money


data Side = Buy | Sell

data Trade src dst fee = T
    { trade_exchange :: ExchangeRate src dst
    , trade_side     :: Side
    , trade_amount   :: Dense src
    , trade_fee      :: Dense fee
    }

executeTrade
    :: (Dense src, Dense dst, Dense fee)
    -> Trade src dst fee
    -> (Dense src, Dense dst, Dense fee)
executeTrade (balanceSrc, balanceDst, balanceFee) T {..} = case trade_side of
    Sell -> (balanceSrc - amountSrc, balanceDst + amountDst, totalFee)
    Buy  -> (balanceSrc + amountSrc, balanceDst - amountDst, totalFee)
  where
    amountSrc = trade_amount
    amountDst = exchange trade_exchange trade_amount
    totalFee  = balanceFee - trade_fee

class BalanceSheet a where
  balance' :: forall name scale . (KnownSymbol name , GoodScale scale) => a -> Maybe (Discrete' name scale)

  balance :: (KnownSymbol name , GoodScale scale) => a -> Discrete' name scale
  balance = fromMaybe (discrete 0) . balance'

type InMemoryBalanceSheet = M.Map String SomeDiscrete

m :: InMemoryBalanceSheet
m = M.fromList
    [ ("ETH", toSomeDiscrete (discrete 0 :: Discrete "ETH" "wei"))
    , ("EUR", toSomeDiscrete (discrete 1000 :: Discrete "EUR" "cent"))
    ]

instance BalanceSheet InMemoryBalanceSheet where
    balance'
        :: forall name scale
         . (KnownSymbol name, GoodScale scale)
        => InMemoryBalanceSheet
        -> Maybe (Discrete' name scale)
    balance' b =
        let c = symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy name)
        in  M.lookup c b >>= fromSomeDiscrete
```